# No output from script run under crontab

Tags: perl, cron

I want to execute a Perl script every two minutes.

This script sends me an email that contains files. It works fine manually.

I tried in a crontab

```
*/2 * * * * /sw/freetools/perl/5.8.8/Linux/rh6/x86_64/bin/perl /home/httpldev/iLicoMetrics/metrique.pl &> /dev/null
```

I also tried with

```
*/2 * * * * /home/httpldev/iLicoMetrics/metrique.pl &> /dev/null
```

but I got no output.

Comment: You should probably try to redirect the output of your execution to a file rather than to `/dev/null` so that you can work out from the error messages it could contain.

Comment: The [cron tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) has excellent debugging information, did you have a look at it?

Comment: thank you every one , i resolve the problem

Comment: Wow! Perl 5.8.8. And it's not the system Perl. How old is your system Perl? :-)

Comment: @maha: If you have found a solution then please write it up as an answer. It's very selfish of you to just disappear once your own problem has been solved. By far the highest value of any Stack Overflow post is to others who may have a similar problem and find it through a search. You have left a page that is completely useless to anyone.

Comment: Sorry @Borodin , the problem is a mistake in the path of Perl , i forgot Rh60 , it's correct syntax for how want to use this . Thank you again for  every one who give me answer.

Comment: @maha: Okay, please write an *answer* below to describe your solution properly.

Answer (score 3):

I find my mistake, i make a mistake in the path of Perl :
/sw/freetools/perl/5.8.8/Linux/rh6/x86_64/bin/perl

/sw/freetools/perl/5.8.8/Linux/rh60/x86_64/bin/perl

Thank you for your help.